# How to change Textarea to Textbox in Html

Tags: html, textbox, textarea

I need to change textarea to textbox, keep every field. This is my html code:

```
<div class="row module-show-option">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-group">
              <label for="select-name">Other car rental preferences</label>
         <div class="box-group">
             <textarea id="transferMess" name="OtherCarRental" value="@modelData["OtherCarRental"].ToString()" class="form-control" placeholder="Any other vehicle rental preferences?" required>@modelData["OtherCarRental"].ToString()</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<input>` with `type="text"` like this, don't need a closing tag.

```
<input type="text" id="transferMess" name="OtherCarRental" value="@modelData["OtherCarRental"].ToString()" class="form-control" placeholder="Any other vehicle rental preferences?" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "textarea" to "input" and give it a "type" attribute called "text"

So instead of:

```
<textarea
```

do this

```
<input type="text"
```

And make sure the closing `</textarea>` tag is also changed to a closing `</input>` tag. Which the first answer given forgot to do.

Like so:

```
<div class="row module-show-option">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-group">
              <label for="select-name">Other car rental preferences</label>
         <div class="box-group">
             <input type="text" id="transferMess" name="OtherCarRental" value="@modelData["OtherCarRental"].ToString()" class="form-control" placeholder="Any other vehicle rental preferences?" required>@modelData["OtherCarRental"].ToString()</input>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```